# Guardar en un ArrayList, los elementos anteriores se repiten

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente código para rellenar una tabla, sin embargo al introducir una segunda vez información y guardarla, cuando el método actualiza la lista, los datos se duplican, por ejemplo: Si introduzco Juan y lo guardo muestra Juan solamente, pero al introducir otro nombre aparece el nombre del segundo objeto y Juan repetido dos veces

```
public void Listar_Contactos() {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) 
    Vista.VentanaAgenda.Tabla_contactos.getModel();
    Object datos[] = new Object[8];
    for (int i= 0; i< arreglo.size(); i++){
        datos[0]= arreglo.get(i).getFoto();
        datos[1]= arreglo.get(i).getNombre();
        datos[2]= arreglo.get(i).getApellido();
        datos[3]= Integer.toString(arreglo.get(i).getMovil());
        datos[4]= Integer.toString(arreglo.get(i).getCasa());
        datos[5]= arreglo.get(i).getPersonal();
        datos[6]= arreglo.get(i).getTrabajo();
        datos[7]= arreglo.get(i).getDireccion();
        modelo.addRow(datos);
    }
```

**arreglo** hace referencia a una ArrayList creada anteriormente y las columnas las tabla las cree con Netbeans.

Creo que es por que el método crea un segundo **DefaultTableModel** a aparte del que crea Netbeans para la tabla, pero no se como arreglarlo

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que se duplica te refieres a que los daros se ven duplicados en la tabla?

Comment: A que el primer dato y un  segundo dato, de haber sido introducido, se muestran dos veces, hasta tres dependiendo las veces que el método entre en función.

Comment: Se muestran múltiples veces, pero ¿dónde?

Comment: En la tabla que tengo con el DefaultTableModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que solo agregas información a la tabla, nunca la limpias. Deberías ejecutar este código primero:

```
int filas = modelo.getRowCount();
for (int i = filas - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    modelo.removeRow(i);
}
```

Luego de eso, ejecuta el código pars ingresar los valores de tu arreglo al modelo.

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza, funciona 100%

Answer (score 1):

Amigo es debido a que el arreglo tienes que instanciarlo dentro del for

```
for (int i= 0; i< arreglo.size(); i++){
    Object datos[] = new Object[8];
    datos[0]= arreglo.get(i).getFoto();
    datos[1]= arreglo.get(i).getNombre();
    datos[2]= arreglo.get(i).getApellido();
    datos[3]= Integer.toString(arreglo.get(i).getMovil());
    datos[4]= Integer.toString(arreglo.get(i).getCasa());
    datos[5]= arreglo.get(i).getPersonal();
    datos[6]= arreglo.get(i).getTrabajo();
    datos[7]= arreglo.get(i).getDireccion();
    modelo.addRow(datos);
}
```

esa es la manera correcta

Comment: Gracias a amigo, pero se sigue duplicando